# Is torque energy? Does the Poynting vector have anything to do with torque?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, torque

My **physics teacher** told us that **Torque** is nothing but energy. I was very skeptical about this as torque is a vector qty. and energy is scalar, and over that torque is literally a force which makes bodies rotate how would it be energy?

Comment: Your physics teacher needs to re-read the chapter on torque, which is NOT energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque is best be defined as the work that can done per unit angle of rotation (as in Joules/radian) by a force acting in a manner that tends to cause a rotation.  (This immediately gives the formula:  Work = Torque x Angle).  This also helps one remember that in doing work, you want the component of force in the direction of motion, and there is a distance involved (along an arc which is proportional to the radius).  As with most rotational quantities, the vector representing torque is defined as being along the axis of rotation (in the same direction as the associated angular displacement vector).

Answer (score 1):

I think think your teacher mistook torque,it is actually a force which has same units as energy so she might have got wrong there torque is a for responsible for rotational energy of object but is not itself a energy like gravitational force is a force but energy due to gravitational force is potential energy. Torque is a moment that has tendency to cause change in angular momentum of object I hope you are clear

Comment: The unit of force is Newton.  The unit of energy is Joule.  They are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of R.W.Bird defines well the relation between torque and energy. An example is when we manually tighten a screw in wood. The total work depends on the torque but also on the number of turns until the final position.

Only because angle is dimensionless, it doesn't mean it can be ignored.